# Add new menu-item in Silverstripe CMS

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm trying to create a new menu item in the Silverstripe CMS. I still do not get it. I do not know what I did wrong. It's about Silverstripe 3.6.

I also tried "/dev/build" and "dev/build?flush=1". But no result.

Footerinfos.php (mysite/code/)

```
class FooterInfos extends ModelAdmin {

public static $managed_models = array('FooterInfo');
static $url_segment = 'footerinfo';
static $menu_icon = 'framework/admin/images/menu-icons/network.png';
static $menu_title = 'Footer';

}
```

Footerinfo.php (mysite/code/)

```
class FooterInfo extends DataExtension {
static $db = array(
    'FooterHead1' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'FooterHead2' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'FooterHead3' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'FooterText1' => 'HTMLText',
    'FooterText2' => 'HTMLText',
    'FooterText3' => 'HTMLText',
);

function getCMSFields() {   
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root', new TabSet('Footer'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', new TextField('FooterHead1', 'Footer - Kop 1'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', $h1=new HTMLEditorField('FooterText1', 'Footer - Tekst 1'));  
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', new TextField('FooterHead2', 'Footer - Kop 2'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', $h2=new HTMLEditorField('FooterText2', 'Footer - Tekst 2'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', new TextField('FooterHead3', 'Footer - Kop 3'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', $h3=new HTMLEditorField('FooterText3', 'Footer - Tekst 3'));  
    $h1->setRows(7);
    $h2->setRows(7);
    $h3->setRows(7);

    return $fields;
}

}
```

---

Update 14:53u:

It has now been possible to create a menu item.
Only I wonder if it's immediately visible to these fields instead of a selection menu. So like the same with the Settings menu, the fields will be displayed immediately.

I do not get to see the fields right away. Only a list of IDs. If you click on that ID, you will only see the fields. That is not the intention. It must be all the fields right away. Because there are no more than 1 footer.

I have translated the code a bit into my language ;)

Voettekst.php

```
class VoetTekst extends DataObject {

static $db = array(
    'VoetKop1' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'VoetKop2' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'VoetKop3' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'VoetTekst1' => 'HTMLText',
    'VoetTekst2' => 'HTMLText',
    'VoetTekst3' => 'HTMLText',
);

public function getCMSFields() {

    return FieldList::create(
        TextField::create('VoetKop1', 'Footer - Kop 1'),
        HTMLEditorField::create('VoetTekst1', 'Footer - Tekst 1')->setRows(7),

        TextField::create('VoetKop2', 'Footer - Kop 2'),
        HTMLEditorField::create('VoetTekst2', 'Footer - Tekst 2')->setRows(7),

        TextField::create('VoetKop3', 'Footer - Kop 3'),
        HTMLEditorField::create('VoetTekst3', 'Footer - Tekst 3')->setRows(7) 
      );

}
}
```

VoettekstAdmin.php

```
class VoettekstAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

private static $managed_models = array('Voettekst');
private static $url_segment = 'voettekst';
private static $menu_icon = 'framework/admin/images/menu-icons/16x16/network.png';
private static $menu_title = 'Voettekst';

}
```

Screenshots:

[First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey3Oc.jpg)

[Second page after click on ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVzZr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

What's in your template? Just simply calling `$FooterInfo` or <% loop $FooterInfo %>` won't work, because your base page class needs to know about it. You could add a method to the Page base like this:

```
class Page extends SiteTree
{
    public function FooterInfo()
    {
        return FooterInfo::get();
    }
}
```

To return the footer info on every page.

Unless you're actually using your DataExtension as DataExtension and apply it to Page that is.

In that case, please provide your config that tells the manifest to apply the data extension (e.g. your `config.yml` )

From the looks of it though, I think you want `FooterInfo` to extend `DataObject`, not `DataExtension`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe starting with SS3.* moving forward things needed to be "private", so maybe try changing your code to:

```
class FooterInfoAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    private static $managed_models = array('FooterInfo');
    private static $url_segment = 'footerinfo';
    private static $menu_icon = 'framework/admin/images/menu-icons/network.png';
    private static $menu_title = 'Footer';
}
```

*** Above answer fixed your first problem...

UPDATE 1::Now for your DataObject

```
class FooterInfo extends DataObject {
    static $db = array(
        'FooterHead1' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'FooterHead2' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'FooterHead3' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'FooterText1' => 'HTMLText',
        'FooterText2' => 'HTMLText',
        'FooterText3' => 'HTMLText',
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        return new FieldList(
            TextField::create('FooterHead1', 'Footer - Kop 1'),
            HTMLEditorField::create('FooterText1', 'Footer - Tekst 1')->setRows(7),

            TextField::create('FooterHead2', 'Footer - Kop 2'),
            HTMLEditorField::create('FooterText2', 'Footer - Tekst 2')->setRows(7),

            TextField::create('FooterHead3', 'Footer - Kop 3'),
            HTMLEditorField::create('FooterText3', 'Footer - Tekst 3')->setRows(7) 

        );
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2::This is a new update to explain how I would redo what you are doing for such a small task that doesn't really need to be managed by ModelAdmin.

I would extend SiteConfig to manage your Footer content. Others might not agree but to me, anything that is "site wide" should be managed in a central location, and SiteConfig is perfect location for that. This way you wouldn't even need a whole new DataObject or new ModelAdmin. See code below:

Place in a new file called `SiteConfigExtension.php`:

```
class SiteConfigExtension extends DataExtension
{
    private static $db = [
        'FooterHead1' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'FooterHead2' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'FooterHead3' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'FooterText1' => 'HTMLText',
        'FooterText2' => 'HTMLText',
        'FooterText3' => 'HTMLText',
    ];

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields){
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', TextField::create('FooterHead1', 'Footer - Kop 1'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', HTMLEditorField::create('FooterText1', 'Footer - Tekst 1')->setRows(7));

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', TextField::create('FooterHead2', 'Footer - Kop 2'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', HTMLEditorField::create('FooterText2', 'Footer - Tekst 2')->setRows(7));

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', TextField::create('FooterHead3', 'Footer - Kop 3'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Footer', HTMLEditorField::create('FooterText3', 'Footer - Tekst 3')->setRows(7));
    }
}
```

Then in your `config.yml` add:

```
SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - SiteConfigExtension
```

Then, run /dev/build, and you should see a new tab in the Settings tab called Footer with your new fields.

UPDATE 3:: maybe you can try this in your DataObject:

```
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = new FieldList(
        new TabSet(
            "Root",
            $tabMain = new Tab(
                TextField::create('FooterHead1', 'Footer - Kop 1'),
                HTMLEditorField::create('FooterText1', 'Footer - Tekst 1')->setRows(7),

                TextField::create('FooterHead2', 'Footer - Kop 2'),
                HTMLEditorField::create('FooterText2', 'Footer - Tekst 2')->setRows(7),

                TextField::create('FooterHead3', 'Footer - Kop 3'),
                HTMLEditorField::create('FooterText3', 'Footer - Tekst 3')->setRows(7)
            ),
        ),
        new HiddenField('ID')
    );

    $this->extend('updateCMSFields', $fields);

    return $fields;
}
```

***Disclaimer: the above code is not tested.

Comment: @Simon Erkelens is correct about your DataObject as well...but I do not think that was your main question at this point...

Comment: This works! Only I wonder if it's immediately visible to these fields instead of a selection menu. So like the same with the Settings menu, the fields will be displayed immediately.

Comment: Yes, once you click on the Footer link/tab on the left (inside the CMS) (modeladmin), you should see all 6 fields immediately. I do not believe you should need to create a tab for them unless you start adding more and more and need to start separating them out into different tabs so it's easier for your user to know where to go to edit things.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not get to see the fields right away. Only a list of IDs. If you click on that ID, you will only see the fields. That is not the intention. It must be all the fields right away. Because there are no more than 1 footer.

Comment: Then there must be some kind of other issue...what version of SS? Is it 3.6?  EDIT: ah, your original post says 3.6, sorry. Can you post your full code to a paste site and give me the links?

Comment: Yeah, it's indeed 3.6 ;) I put the code in a new post. And, unfortunately, I do not have a link because I work locally on my computer. I have translated the code a bit into my language ;)

Comment: ok, I updated my comment to recommend what @Gavin also said/updated. But I now see your comment that you do not want it to function that way. I wonder if you can find an example to use ModelAdmin that doens't use the GridField to manage the dataobjects, as I believe that's the intended functionality.

Comment: Yes, the example is there. Because that's the way you click on the menu item "Settings". Then there are fill fields with the "Site Title", "Tagline" etc without the GridField. I want that too, but then for the footer, as it's own menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your above answer, `$fields = parent::getCMSFields();` is used on pages, not dataobjects.

The easier way is to use the following:

```
function getCMSFields() {
  $fields = singleton( $this->ClassName )->getFrontendFields();
  return $fields;
}
```

If you want more control, you can use something like:

```
function getCMSFields() {
  return FieldList::create(
    TextField::create('FooterHead1', 'Footer - Kop 1'),
    HTMLEditorField::create('FooterText1', 'Footer - Tekst 1')->setRows(7)
  );
}
```

Comment: I often use `$fields = parent::getCMSFields()` in my DataObjects, cause that calls the scaffolder and then I don't have to create each field manually.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off using `SiteConfig` for this as you only really want one footer. Data Objects are used for multiple records.

**mysite/code/CustomSiteConfig.php**

```
class CustomSiteConfig extends DataExtension {

  private static $db = array(
    'VoetKop1' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'VoetKop2' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'VoetKop3' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'VoetTekst1' => 'HTMLText',
    'VoetTekst2' => 'HTMLText',
    'VoetTekst3' => 'HTMLText'
  );

  public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Footer', array(
      TextField::create('VoetKop1', 'Footer - Kop 1'),
      HTMLEditorField::create('VoetTekst1', 'Footer - Tekst 1')->setRows(7),

      TextField::create('VoetKop2', 'Footer - Kop 2'),
      HTMLEditorField::create('VoetTekst2', 'Footer - Tekst 2')->setRows(7),

      TextField::create('VoetKop3', 'Footer - Kop 3'),
      HTMLEditorField::create('VoetTekst3', 'Footer - Tekst 3')->setRows(7) 
    ));
  }
}
```

**mysite/_config/extensions.yml**

```
SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - CustomSiteConfig
```

Now in your templates, you can use `$SiteConfig.variable` to access the variables. To grab the first title you can use `$SiteConfig.VoetKop1`

This would usually be in a template include.

**themes/themename/templates/Includes/Footer.ss**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-4 small-12 columns">
    <h5>$SiteConfig.VoetKop1</h5>
    <div class="typography">$SiteConfig.VoetTekst1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-4 small-12 columns">
    <h5>$SiteConfig.VoetKop2</h5>
    <div class="typography">$SiteConfig.VoetTekst2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-4 small-12 columns">
    <h5>$SiteConfig.VoetKop3</h5>
    <div class="typography">$SiteConfig.VoetTekst3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you would use `<% include Footer %>

This would usually occur in the **themes/themename/templates/Page.ss** file.

Don't forget to change **themename** with your themes folder.

Under the **Settings** link in the admin, there will now be a tab called **Footer** with these fields.

This code isn't tested but it should work.

Comment: I used to do that too. But I do not want to. Because content managers can not customize other site configuration settings. But they may adjust the footer. That's why it has to be set apart.

Comment: You can use http://api.silverstripe.org/en/3.6/class-Member.html#_inGroup to display different fields to different users.